# Should I book my apartment now or while I'm there?

Tags: europe, germany, international-travel

I am going to Berlin, Germany for approximately 90 days in about three and a half months. I am planning on staying in a furnished apartment the entire 90 days that I am there. We've found apartments listed on Craigslist, wg-gesucht.de, zwischenmiete.de and a few others.

We've been told it's best to fly in and stay in a hotel for the first few days while we scout out apartments before booking them. This is what we'd like to do if it's possible since we've never been to Berlin. Or, should we risk it and book them now without seeing them in person?

Comment: I don’t think that this can be answered in its current form, nor would this be useful to others on this site.

Comment: I would thought that is common sense to see on the spot apartments for long-term rentals. You might not like the neighboorhood, or the building, noises, defects, or even the landlord.

Comment: Booking now will be cheaper, and likely have a larger selection available. But the risks mentioned by others apply. If you know someone in Berlin, you could ask them to go check out some places for you and send pictures.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes that is what I'm thinking, but was hoping for someone who's done it to provide guidance.